# Update material field of an already created material in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, idoc, sap-erp

Hi we created a material in SAP ERP, and an IDoc was send to Hybris, but when we change one of the fields in SAP it does not create a new idoc, and no update is generated in Hybris.

I am thinking on editing the first idoc and resend it, since I am not familiar with the CSV update in Hybris.

Can this be done and the new idoc will overwrite the material field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hybris generally update item, not delete or update unused fields. But it is depending on your integration. If you trigger IDOC again, you can see updates.